# How to get optimal result when converting SVG to PDF with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

In Windows 10, I use ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16. When I execute this command-line:

```
magick clocky.svg test.pdf
```

... then I get a PDF where the image in the PDF is very pixelated:

[image]

This is the source SVG image: https://svgshare.com/s/V0f

How can I get an optimal result when converting SVG to PDF without pixelation with ImageMagick?

Isn't there a way to include the SVG natively in the PDF, so the image in the PDF looks always smooth at all zoom values? (Like it is obviously done by Inkscape when saving an SVG to PDF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you would specify a density before reading the SVG and then resize afterwards. So

```
magick -density 288 clocky.svg -resize 25% test.pdf
```

288=4*72 so we resize by 1/4=25%

Comment: The image in the PDF is still pixelated at higher zoom values in the PDF viewer: https://i.imgur.com/1DgEWej.png The problem obviously is that IM first converts the SVG to a SMALL pixel image and then blows it up to full size inside the PDF. Isn't it possible that IM embeds the SVG natively in the PDF without converting it first to a pixel image?

Comment: No, IM cannot simply put the svg data into a PDF. IM use one of several tools to rasterize the SVG and then put that image into the PDF, i.e. RSVG or Inkscape apart from its own renderer. You could skip the resize, but keep the -density 300 or 600 and see if that helps. Otherwise, I do not know of any SVG to PDF tool. But there might be such.